# Parsing error: Unexpected character '​' in an array of objects in create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app

I am working on a create-react-app based application and I have been getting issues related to ES5 syntax and sometimes for plain js as shown in the attached picture. I have tried updating all npm packages but no luck. Anyone have any idea why this is and how it can be fixed.
This is the line of code that compiler is complaining that **Parsing error: Unexpected character '​'** in the following line of code.

```
const data = ​​[{ value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' }, { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' }];
```

[Screenshot of the code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHRJ0.png)

Comment: When I pasted the code in the console I noticed 2 `'` before the `[`. Which cannot be seen for some reason.

Comment: You have two zero width spaces after `const data =`. If you remove those and replace them with a regular space it should work.